# Запятая перед "и", подразумевая "а также"

Tags: пунктуация

Есть такое предложение:

> Молодым девушкам можно сделать себе короткую стрижку пикси, которая
>   очень современная, **и** проста в ухаживании и обращении.

Меня берут сомнения ставить ли перед "и" запятую или нет.

Если перефразировать так:

> Молодым девушкам можно сделать себе короткую стрижку пикси, которая
>   очень современная, а также проста в ухаживании и обращении.

То безусловно понятно, что запятая нужна. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Молодым девушкам можно сделать себе короткую стрижку пикси, которая очень современна и проста в ухаживании и обращении.

Запятая не нужна: **современна и проста, в ухаживании и обращении**; здесь не повторяющий союз И...И, а  два одиночных союза И с разными функциями.

Comment: Получается, что не важно подразумевает ли "и" смысл "а также" или нет.

Comment: Молодым девушкам можно сделать себе короткую стрижку пикси, которая очень современна, а также проста в ухаживании и обращении. Союз А ТАКЖЕ имеет присоединительное значение, то есть придает сообщению добавочный характер. В данном случае этот вариант проще для чтения и понимания, поэтому можно использовать его.